# The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '<APPID>'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax7

We started having this problem shortly after we started using DYN365O Update 3. Our code worked for a while then one day in mid-January stopped working. We have a ticket into Microsoft but was hoping someone has found a workaround. The following error happens when our code tries to connect:

> Response Code (1004) {"error":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator
>   has not consented to use the application with ID ''. Send an
>   interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace
>   ID: d1775f71-ac60-4d12-ace5-39b52452a5c7\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   38e3b5c6-52c2-4ea9-9ad1-67230e246b40\r\nTimestamp: 2017-01-29
>   21:42:43Z"}

I was able to use the code here (https://github.com/Microsoft/Dynamics-AX-Integration) to recreate the problem. Here is the relevant section:

```
    string aadTenant = ClientConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryTenant;
    string aadClientAppId = ClientConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryClientAppId;
    string aadResource = ClientConfiguration.Default.ActiveDirectoryResource;

    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadTenant);

    // OAuth through username and password.
    string username = ClientConfiguration.Default.UserName;
    string password = ClientConfiguration.Default.Password;

    // Get token object
    var userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
    aadResource,
    aadClientAppId,
    userCredential).Result;
```

1. When pointing to our Update 2 (August Update) DYN365O instance
   everything works perfectly.
2. Changing the URI to point to Update3 we begin to see these errors.

I have searched the internet and I have done everything suggested including:

1. Setting oauth2AllowImplicitFlow = true in the manifest for the Azure
   App.
2. Under permissions for the APP in AAD I have used the Grant
   Permissions to "grant permissions for all accounts in the
   directory".
3. Altering the call to AcquireTokenAsync to include
   "prompt=admin_consent". I am presented with the prompt screen but
   even after entering the AAD admin userid/password I get the same
   error.
4. Tried other users for 3.
5. Verified that the user in DYN365O (under System Administration >>
   Users) is identical in both our Update2 and Update3 instances and is
   a System Administrator.

Comment: Is the application id in the error your app's id?

Comment: Can you share what your Login URL looks like? Can you share the specific client ID in the error message?

Comment: Yes the client ID is the same in the error as the one  that I am using. I was on with Microsoft today and we tried to use excel to connect to the Odata Feed and we get the same error. Excel does not use an AppID. So this issue is not with the APPId.